# Polymorphism and dealing with native types

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, subclass, superclass

I am trying to understand Polymorphism and the inheritance relationship between a superclass and its subclass. I know that when dealing with an object that's instantiated from the subclass either as its native type, the subclass or as it's inherited or to extend a type the Superclass. What is the objects native type? What are differences between the three types of Polymorphism?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please clarify or re-word your question.

Comment: If this topic has already been answered, then please provide a link. Thank you for your help!

Comment: "native" type?  Are you talking about JNI or something?

Comment: If you have a problem understanding some book or tutorial, please provide the full quote (with the link, if possible) and then specify what seems to be not clear.

Comment: @Jon189283 You seem to have confused SO with a website where the contributors can read your mind.

Comment: You are confused about native and primitive types. Read this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two terms that might help:

- dynamic type
- static type

An object has a type, that is the type that comes after `new`. But when you have polymorphism, there are different ways to refer to the object:

```
Integer v = Integer.valueOf(123);
Number n = v;
```

Here, `n` and `v` refer to the same object, but in different ways. This is allowed because `Integer` is a subclass of `Number` and `Number` is a superclass of `Integer`.

Now, `n` has two different types. The *static type*, which is `Number`, which appears in the text of the program. It also has a *dynamic type*, which is `Integer`, which is its real type. I assume the real type, or the dynamic type, is what you mean by "native type".

With this knowledge, we can look at the different types of polymorphism:

**Ad-hoc polymorphism (aka overloading in Java):** You can have multiple functions with the same name and parameter lists, differing only by parameter type. Which function will be chosen will depend on the *static* type.

```
public String add(String a, String b) {
    return a + b;
}

public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

add("a", "b"); // calls first version of add
add(1, 2); // calls second version of add
```

**Parametric polymorphism (aka generics in Java):** You can have the same functions "parameterized" by a type argument T. Which functions are available on T depend on the static type.

```
public <T extends Number> boolean lessThan(T a, T b) {
    // compareTo is available because T has the static type Number
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0;
}
```

**Subtype polymorphism (aka overriding):** Which function is called depends on the dynamic type.

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract void speak();
}

public class Dog {
    public void speak() { System.out.println("Woof"); }
}

public class Cat {
    public void speak() { System.out.println("Meow"); }
}

Animal a = new Dog();
Animal b = new Cat();
a.speak(); // says Woof - because dynamic type is Dog
b.speak(); // says Meow - because dynamic type is Cat
```